# Unity equivalent of GKAgent

Tags: unity

Does Unity have an equivalent to GKAgent in Apples GamePlayKit to define agents, goals and behaviours out of the box?

Would this be the unity AI system? Or more likely a 3rd party aaset?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity doesn't have a built-in goal-oriented AI agent. You need to write your own or get a third-party library.

**Edit:** I looked it up a little bit more and it seems GKAgent is not about GOAP, but it is about steering behaviours. The answer still holds though, Unity does not have built-in support for steering behaviours. However, there are many drop-in libraries that you can use for this purpose. A quick search with the keywords "Unity steering behaviours" should give you plenty of resources. Here is one that I found: https://github.com/ricardojmendez/UnitySteer